# Dynamically wrap words in anchor element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm trying to write a function that uses jQuery to dynamically wrap words in anchor tags. Specifically, I want each instance of authors' names in blog posts to link to a page of their posts. What I have now doesn't seem to indicate any errors, but it does not replace my names with links:

```
( function( $ ) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function linkAuthorRefs( authors, newName ) {
      for( i = 0; i < authors.length; i++ ) {
        var author = authors[i],
            regExAuthor = "/" + author + "/gi",
            $elements = $( '.entry-content p:contains( "' + author + '" ), .entry-summary p:contains( "' + author + '" )' );
        if( ! newName ) { var newName = author.toLowerCase(); }
        for( j = 0; j < $elements.length; j++ ) {
          e = $elements[j];
          e.html(e.html().replace( regExAuthor, '<a title="View all posts by ' + newName + '" href="http://aaronandrebekah.com/?category=' + newName + '" rel="author">' + author + '</a>' ) );
        }
      }
    }
    var authorNames = [ "Aaron", "Rebekah" ];
    linkAuthorRefs( authorNames );
    linkAuthorRefs( [ "Bekah" ], "rebekah" );
  });
} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: use [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method.

Comment: 1) do you need all that jQUery no-conflict? 2) contains is case sensitive, there are insensitive versions here at SO 3) why a named function, just create one author array and use each on it

Comment: mplungjan, 1) I think I do, but I'm new at this so maybe not. I belive I saw it reccomended to avoid breaking bad WordPress plugins. 2) Are you suggesting I add a method that's similar to contains to my code? 3) I named it so I could send an array sometimes, and multiple variables sometimes, in case of nicknames, like Bekah, which I would like to link to Rebekah's page. Also, I was getting errors with each and couldn't figure out why so I switched to for loops.

Comment: @C-link why is replaceWith() better than html()? I still have to use replace() to change the string that will be my new html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions. After a lot more research, the following works well!

```
$.each( [ "Aaron", "Rebekah" ], function( i, j ) {
  var author = j,
      authorLower = author.toLowerCase(),
      regExAuthor = RegExp( "\\b" + author + "\\b", "gi"),
      anchoredText = '<a title="View all posts by ' + authorLower + '" href="http://aaronandrebekah.com/?category=' + authorLower + '" rel="author">' + author + '</a>',
      $elements = $( '.entry-content p, .entry-summary p' );
  $elements.each( function() {
    var $par = $( this );
    $par.html( $par.html().replace( regExAuthor, anchoredText ) );
  });
});
```